# Changes references

Tags: bibliographies, citing

My cites had a format (1) and y want [1]

my code:

```
\usepackage[ pdftex, plainpages = false, pdfpagelabels, 
             pdfpagelayout = OneColumn, % display single page, advancing flips the page - Sasa Tomic
             bookmarks,
             bookmarksopen = true,
             bookmarksnumbered = true,
             breaklinks = true,
             linktocpage,
             pagebackref,
             colorlinks = true,
             linkcolor = blue,
             urlcolor  = blue,
             citecolor = red,
             anchorcolor = green,
             hyperindex = true,
             hyperfigures
             ]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .jpg, .pdf}

\pdfcompresslevel=9
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show how you build your bibliography with a short, **compilable** tex code. Do not forget to add two bib entrys to your question! Your shown code snippet has nothing to do with building the bibliography or the way of citing ...

Comment: Citing is not `cross-referencing`, so [tag:cross-referencing] is wrong

Answer (score 1):

If your numeric-style citation call-outs have the form `(1)`, `(2)`, etc. it must because something in your code is inducing this non-default behavior; the LaTeX default is `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

If you can't identify what's in your code that's causing the citation call-outs to be encased in round parentheses, do consider either one (but not both simultaneously!) of the following suggestions:

- If you're using the  `cite` citation management package, be sure to issue the instructions

  ```
  \renewcommand\citeleft{[}
  \renewcommand\citeright{]}
  ```

  after loading the `cite` package.
- If you're using the `natbib` citation management package, be sure to either load it with the options `numbers` and `square` or to issue the instruction

  ```
  \setcitestyle{numbers,square}
  ```

  after loading `natbib`.

Happy LaTeXing!